# Can you store selected sql query values in the url and then retrive them with $_GET?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to make it so that when a users clicks one of the rows,it will take them to a new page whose link is given as the value of the row they selected and then retrieve the value with $_GET["timesub"].

Anyone know how to do this?

```
mysql_select_db("RRRC", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mainreq WHERE roomnum=$loc");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th> Submitted </th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><a href="roomdata.php?timestamp= . $row['timesub'] . "> . $row['timesub'] . </a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Regardless of the other selected answers, please please please do not do this: `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mainreq WHERE roomnum=$loc");`. Read up on SQL injections and use bind variables instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that  $row['timesub'] identifies a row in your data set (I doubt it), just fix your echo instruction as:

```
echo "<td><a href=\"roomdata.php?timestamp=" . $row['timesub'] . "\">" . $row['timesub'] . "</a></td>";
```

Escaping the html quotes properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td><a href='roomdata.php?timestamp=".$row['timesub']."'>".$row['timesub']."</a></td>";
```

Close the outer " before the . concatenator, replace the inner " with '

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to use the row's primary key to reference your get query; but yes - this can be done.

All you have to do is store the get data into a sanitized variable, and perform the required SQL lookup / data display.

EX:

```
$roomnum=mysql_real_escape_string(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $_GET['roomnum']));
```

Now, given that "roomnum" is your primary key just look it up and display:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mainreq WHERE roomnum='$roomnum'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><a href="roomdata.php?timestamp= . $row['timesub'] . "> . $row['timesub'] . </a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```